# How to stop a door from banging while closing

Tags: doors, hinges

Besides closing it very slowly, any good tricks / gadgets that will slow down the door so it doesn't close with a thud?

Comment: They make [soft close hinges](http://www.amazon.com/Silentia-Soft-Close-Hinges-Frame-Overlay/dp/B001N2WAFC) for cabinets, but I don't think they make these for a large entry doors (yet).

Answer (score 8):

There are a few things you can do:

- Check the hinges and use a level to see that the door is square. A heavy door hung incorrectly can slam heavily. Check [this guide at national contractors](https://web.archive.org/web/20170414143520/http://www.nationalcontractors.com:80/articles/interior_door_leveling.html) for how to level a door. Some tips from it: check that the hinges are tight, not too heavily greased, and the same distance from the frame.
- Install a closer arm (can be expensive)

[image: Door closer]
<sub>(source: [keylessaccesslocks.com](https://www.keylessaccesslocks.com/media/catalog/category/Sargent_Door_Closers.jpg))</sub>

- If the door isn't closing too hard, but makes a fair amount of noise, try putting some small felt pads on the inside of the jamb to soften the closure.

[image: Felt pads]

Answer (score 5):

You could also install from 2-> several dampers like these ones depending how heavy the door is or how well you want to dampen it - for example you have a heavy draft that SLAMS the door shut several will be recomeneded to adsorb the doors speed.  These work well if installed fairly well.

[image]

Either into the frame somehow- slighlty countersinking it so it hides nicely, or not- its up to you and your skills.
[image]

Or just using a provided housing the will mount flush onto the frame of your door in any position that is best for you.

[image]

Comment: I found the dampers for cabinet doors, but not for a room door. I am looking for options for the bathroom door / bedroom doors. They make a decent amount of noise while closing manually.

Comment: yea- those are the ones-- just use 3 top - center bottom or something that suits your needs. it would be best to have them inserted in the frame- looks better.

Answer (score 2):

An other couple of possible hardware solutions to look into (exact size & weight of the door will determine if they are appropriate or not)...

Cheaper end of the market, **Chain Spring Door Closer:**

[image: Chain Spring Door Closer]

High end of the market, **Concealed (Automatic) Door Closer:**

[image: Concealed (Automatic) Door Closer]

Comment: These would do the opposite of what original poster wishes. These are door closers (for fire safety), and these particular types would cause door to accelerate towards the frame.